# Gruff Pie chart - description/legend next to each pie slice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, gruff

I have two questions. I'm using Gruff library to draw charts in Ruby on Rails project.
Is it possible make description next to each pie slice, like on image below.

[image]

Second question is about spacing between slices. Is it possible to make some space between slices using Gruff library (something like on image below)

[image]

Comment: Your first quesiton's answer is yes. i have no-idea for your second question. see http://www.rubydoc.info/github/topfunky/gruff/Gruff/Pie

Comment: Could You tell me what attribute I should change to make description next to each pie slice, because I can't see it in documentation?

Comment: First of all, make sure that the gem which you used is this one :https://github.com/topfunky/gruff.git

Comment: You can see many of example like this one https://github.com/topfunky/gruff/blob/master/test/output/pie_keynote.png is more or less similar than your first pie.

Comment: any luck on creating 3d pie chart as shown in second figure ?